# return None and not print anything out of function

Tags: python

I am trying to return None and not print anything outside of the function. For example once I have called the `doAtest` Function, if return `True` I will print "Valid Information". If it return `False`, I will print "Error Invalid Letter".

However, what I am trying to achieve here is once it enters the `else` block in `doAtest` Function, I just want it to print "Error: Invalid Format" only.

Right now it prints "Error: Invalid Format" and "Error: Invalid Letter" though I return None. Is there a way for me to return a Null function such that It will not print anything out of the function?

```
def doAtest(user):
    #Do some calculations       

    if(some condition):          
        if(some condition):                                                
            return True
        else:
            return False

    elif(some condition):     
        if (some condition):
            return True
        else:
            return False

    else:
        print("Error: Invalid Format")
        return None  


user_raw = input("Enter your employee code :")

if doAtest(user_raw):                   # Here prints True condition
    print("Valid Information")

else:
    print("Error: Invalid Letter")      # Here prints False condition
```

Comment: `None` is considered "falsy".  If `doAtest` returns `None`, then the `else` clause will be executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Your problem

As @Patrick Haugh explained in the comments, `None` is considered "falsy". So with the following code, if `doAtest()` returns `None`, the `else` block will be executed:

```
if doAtest(user_raw):
    print("Valid Information")
else:
    print("Error: Invalid Letter")
```

### Solution

You can check if your result `is True`, and then check if `is not None` instead of using `else`.

Also, you might want to group together all your calls to `print()` by adding an `else` clause that would handle `None`, instead of handling it inside the `doAtest()` function.

```
result = doAtest(user_raw)

if result is True:
    print("Valid Information")
elif result is not None:
    print("Error: Invalid Letter")
#else:
#    print("Error: Invalid Format")
```

Comment: @RonanBoiteau worked perfectly fine for me. I understand that None is considered as falsy now. Thanks!

Comment: There's a big difference between `result` and `result is True` - so depends what the desired flow is. `if result` will handle all truthy like things and the `elif result is not None` will be non-truthy values that aren't explicitly None. However, `if result is True` will handle only where `True` is the actual object returned and the `elif result is not None` will handle any values that aren't explicitly `None` and weren't equal to `True` - so left over truth/falsey values - it's important to understand the difference there.